# PHP PCRE expression problem - get digits of a string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need a regex expression (PCRE) to match a integer number inside a string, being the string like : image89.jpg

I've tried many options without success.

I'm using preg_replace() by the way

My last attempt :

```
preg_replace('(\d+)', '$1', 'image89.jpg');
```

Comment: Besides not having a proper delimiter (most PREG patterns will use `/`, but other matching characters can be used), the only thing that replacement would accomplish is to return the exact same string you provided as input.

Comment: you want to match or to replace ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\d+/', 'image89.jpg', $matches);
$digit = $matches[0];
```

If you plan to find multiple sets of digits in the same string, you'll want to use `preg_match_all`.